# Tracing amounts in R

Tags: r, loops, trace

I currently have a data frame that looks like this

```
Seq<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
Direction<-c("INCOMING","OUTGOING", "INCOMING", "OUTGOING", "OUTGOING","INCOMING", "INCOMING", "OUTGOING","INCOMING", "OUTGOING", "OUTGOING")
Amount<-c(500,200,300,400,200,300,200,100,200,100,50)
df<-cbind(Seq, Direction, Amount)
df
      Seq  Direction  Amount
 [1,] "1"  "INCOMING" "500" 
 [2,] "2"  "OUTGOING" "200" 
 [3,] "3"  "INCOMING" "300" 
 [4,] "4"  "OUTGOING" "400" 
 [5,] "5"  "OUTGOING" "200" 
 [6,] "6"  "INCOMING" "300" 
 [7,] "7"  "INCOMING" "200" 
 [8,] "8"  "OUTGOING" "100" 
 [9,] "9"  "INCOMING" "200" 
[10,] "10" "OUTGOING" "100" 
[11,] "11" "OUTGOING" "50"
```

I want to create two extra columns called 'Traced Amount' and 'Trace Reference'.

Traced amount follows the following rule: select the earliest 'INCOMING' in the sequence, then if an 'OUTGOING' is next, then record that 'OUTGOING' amount.

Here is where it get tricky: theTraced reference column selects the earliest 'INCOMING' in the Sequence and gives it the number 1. If an 'OUTGOING' follows it is given the same number. When a new 'INCOMING' occurs, it gives it 2, and the following 'OUTGOING' gets 2, and so it continues.

The data frame I should have in the end should look like this.

```
      Seq  Direction  Amount Trace_Reference Traced_Amount
 [1,] "1"  "INCOMING" "500"  "1"             " "          
 [2,] "2"  "OUTGOING" "200"  "1"             "200"        
 [3,] "3"  "INCOMING" "300"  "2"             ""           
 [4,] "4"  "OUTGOING" "400"  "2"             "400"        
 [5,] "5"  "OUTGOING" "200"  "2"             "200"        
 [6,] "6"  "INCOMING" "300"  "3"             ""           
 [7,] "7"  "INCOMING" "200"  "4"             ""           
 [8,] "8"  "OUTGOING" "100"  "4"             "100"        
 [9,] "9"  "INCOMING" "200"  "5"             ""           
[10,] "10" "OUTGOING" "100"  "5"             "100"        
[11,] "11" "OUTGOING" "50"   "5"             "50"
```

Any help on how to write a code that generates these two columns would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First of all, with `cbind` you are creating a matrix and all columns are coerced to a least common denominator, class `"character"`.
The right way to create the table is

```
Seq<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
Direction<-c("INCOMING","OUTGOING", "INCOMING", "OUTGOING", "OUTGOING","INCOMING", "INCOMING", "OUTGOING","INCOMING", "OUTGOING", "OUTGOING")
Amount<-c(500,200,300,400,200,300,200,100,200,100,50)

df <- data.frame(Seq, Direction, Amount)
```

Now for the question.
Use a logical index to detect the incoming rows and since `FALSE/TRUE` are coded as `0/1`, `cumsum` will increment the incoming counter.
Then negate the logical index to assign the outgoing amounts to a new column.

```
i <- df$Direction == "INCOMING"
df$Trace_Reference <- cumsum(i)

df$Traced_Amount <- NA_real_
df$Traced_Amount[!i] <- df$Amount[!i]
```

Answer (score 0):

About **Traced Amount**, I don't see exceptions to the fact that in seems to only record the value in the "Direction" column, so for that I simply suggest doing:

```
dplyr::mutate(df, Traced_Amount = ifelse(Direction == "OUTGOING", Direction, ""))
```

Since this doesn't seem to be your definition, I suggest you provide an example of exception to what I said.

As for **Trace_Reference**, I don't see an easy way to do it than using a for loop, which will take a long time:

```
trace_reference_counter <- 1
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if (df[i, "Direction"] == "INCOMING") {
        df[i, "Trace_Reference"] <- trace_reference_counter
        trace_reference_counter <- trace_reference_counter + 1
    } else{
        df[i, "Trace_Reference"] <- trace_reference_counter
    } 
}
```